# What's the effect of transitive dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I lately integrated Crashlytics into my side projects and found the transitive option on dependency declaration like this in the setup guideline https://dev.twitter.com/crashlytics/android/build-tools:

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:KIT_VERSION@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

So what's the effect of that option? Why should I need it? I've already looked into the **Manage transitive dependencies** at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html but I couldn't connect the dots.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `transitive = false` on the `crashlytics` library causes gradle to ignore all libraries required by `crashlytics` (="transient libraries") and not download and link them.

You would have to either manually add the required libraries to your project or rely on other transient libraries added by other dependencies.

Default for gradle is `transitive = true`.

Examples and full explanation here: http://www.devsbedevin.net/android-understanding-gradle-dependencies-and-resolving-conflicts/